# Maintain list of excluded directories for grep alias

Tags: bash, alias, brace-expansion

I like to use grep recursively but am constantly finding directories that I want to omit.  I omit them using bracket expansion with --exclude-dir like so:
`grep -r --exclude-dir={obj,compile} main`

I can alias this:
`alias grep='grep -r --exclude-dir={obj,compile}'`
but I would like to maintain a variable I can update and export and continue using the alias as is rather than updating the alias every time I encounter a directory I want to ignore:

```
GREP_SKIP=obj,compile
alias grep='grep -r --exclude-dir={$GREP_SKIP}'
```

I add this to my .bashrc and it doesn't work.  I want to have $GREP_SKIP evaluated every time the grep alias is used.  From what I can tell, the bracket expansion isn't happening at all.

Any ideas on what I can do to pull this off with this approach or is there a different approach that will accomplish the same thing?

Comment: You are better off updating the alias. Variable expansion doesn't occur within brace-expansion. You really want to avoid `eval` (which is the only other option), But `eval` is just one-character away from `evil`...

Comment: Have a look at [3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) in the manual: brace expansion happens **before** variable expansion. This is why it "doesn't work" putting variables in a brace expansion.

Comment: Perhaps the question you want to ask yourself: what do you want to edit to add new excluded directories? The .bashrc to edit the alias, the .bashrc to edit the variable, a test file holding the list of directories? What will be easiest for you?

Comment: I was hoping to update an easily remembered variable and have it affect my grep alias in real time.  If that isn't possible, then updating the literal list of directories in the alias in .bashrc and applying that alias is close enough.  Thanks!